# Одновременный доступ к GUI

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, http, google-docs

Условия задачи такие, есть клиент, есть оператор. Перед ними терминал, на котором определенная форма (например анкета на кредит). При любом изменении каких -то полей на этой форме, эти изменения отображаются на экране оператора. Клиентов и операторов может быть любое число.На данный момент я сделал WCF сервис, к которому подключаются и клиент и оператор, если данные пришли он помещаются БД, либо по запросу извлекаются от туда по запросу, но это сильно грузит канал. Вопрос, как организовать архитектуру программы? Есть ли технологии позволяющие решить задачу впрямую? Т.е например гугл докс предоставляет одновременный доступ к файлу, при этом не делая постоянных запросов.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы рекомендовал связку  WPF(MVVM)<->WCF<->Entity<->SQL

При этом считаю, что синхронизацию лучше и быстрее выполнять средствами самого WCF, оставив SQL только функцию хранения промежуточных и итоговых данных.

*P.S. К сожалению, не сразу заметил тэги "Web" и "http".
Если решение использовать веб-клиент окончательно и бесповоротно, то рекомендую 
связку ASP.Net MVC<->WCF<->Entity<->SQL. Однако при этом данные должны будут обновляться через AJAX или схожими способами, что приведет к регулярному обращению к сервису. Впрочем, при правильной настройке WCF и использовании асинхронных методов нужно будет очень постараться чтобы его перегрузить. Едва ли кредитный договор будут одновременно заполнять тысячи клиентов одной и той же кредитной организации.*